# Laravel Eloquent Relationship Join

Tags: php, laravel-8

carts:-

| id | product_name | price |
| --- | --- | --- |

ratings:-

| id | product_id | user_id |
| --- | --- | --- |

I have these two table. And i have defined a relationship in product model for geting rating of particular product. and output of the code is this:-

```
"data": [
        {
            "id": 4200,
            "name": "Anti gravity Beer Cake",
            "modal": "",
            "price": 1800,
            "discount": 0,
            "quantity": 20,
            "discription": "Good Quality Product!",
            "p_status": "active",
            "m_id": 664,
            "product_link": "anti-gravity-beer-cake--6040c2b317894",
            "product_picture": " ",
            "weight": 0,
            "weight_type": "Kilogram",
            "rating": {
                "id": 4,
                "u_id": 1,
                "product_id": 4200,
                "subject": null,
                "ratings": 4,
                "review": null,
                "type": "rating"
            }
        },
{
            "id": 4200,
            "name": "Anti gravity Beer Cake",
            "modal": "",
            "price": 1800,
            "discount": 0,
            "quantity": 20,
            "discription": "Good Quality Product!",
            "p_status": "active",
            "m_id": 664,
            "product_link": "anti-gravity-beer-cake--6040c2b317894",
            "product_picture": " ",
            "weight": 0,
            "weight_type": "Kilogram",
            "rating": {
                "id": 5,
                "u_id": 1,
                "product_id": 4200,
                "subject": null,
                "ratings": 5,
                "review": null,
                "type": "rating"
            }
        }
```

But i want product having high rating first. How i an do it?
product model:-

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class product extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    
    public function rating(){
        return $this->hasOne(ratings_and_review::class)->orderBy('ratings','DESC');
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you try with 'rating' instead of 'ratings'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try and sort the collection after getting the data from the DB, example:

```
$products = Product::with('rating')->get()->sortByDesc('rating.ratings');
```

you can refer to the collection documentation on laravel:
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections

Answer (score 0):

Try This one....

```
public function rating(){
      return $this->hasOne(ratings_and_review::class)->sortByDesc('rating','ratings');
}
```